# Does an Al Jazeera video suggest that a rocket caused the Ahli hospital explosion?

Tags: israel-hamas-war

[Video shows rocket fired from Gaza make sharp turn back before blast seen at hospital](https://www.cnn.com/videos/world/2023/10/18/gaza-rocket-hospital-blast-vpx.cnn) (CNN):

> Video from Al Jazeera appears to show a rocket fired from Gaza make a sudden turn moments before a deadly blast was seen at the Al-Ahli Baptist Hospital in Gaza.

Comment: This is the position of the US and Israeli governments, based on their assessments. Whether *everyone* is convinced is [another matter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVQALHmgo8U). I'm voting to close this as a current event, still being investigated by various entities. See https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4990/israel-hamas-conflict

Comment: One thing that is rather certain from aftermath photos is that there wasn't much shrapnel on the ground, at least hitting the nearby walls or trees. So that kinda narrows it down to a rocket motor or some fuel-air/incendiary kind of bomb. None of the surrounding buildings burned down though, just the cars in the yard.

Comment: Aside, some people were skeptical of the casualty figure too (and the US said it's on the low side of 100-300 victims) but that's rather consistent with a blast bomb dropped on a crowd (be it a large rocket motor or something designed for that--see [Myanmar](https://apnews.com/article/myanmar-thermobaric-bombing-f1902357415217f46abceffab23f7995).)

Comment: As for the Gaza event, one crucial bit of evidence, namely any weapon fragment[s] has apparently been "cleaned up" by Hamas from the site before journalists were invited, so we probably won't have certainty in that regard.

Comment: Yes, it *does* suggest it. What is your reason for doubting that they suggested it? Or are you doubting that this is what they were suggesting? Or are you doubting that it was actually an Al Jazeera video?

Comment: @RayButterworth well, for starters, the rocket blows up in midair

Comment: Here is a more detailed analysis by the Wall Street Journal: https://www.wsj.com/video/video-analysis-shows-gaza-hospital-hit-by-failed-rocket-meant-for-israel/120A1C22-BA32-418E-8837-BC4141FEFB00.html

Comment: Some additional relevant links: [1](https://www.reuters.com/world/french-military-intelligence-says-israeli-strike-not-behind-gaza-hospital-blast-2023-10-20/), [2](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/israel-did-not-strike-gaza-hospital-canada-says-2023-10-22/)

Comment: Hamas seems to claim now that there's nothing left whatsoever of the weapon https://www.nytimes.com/2023/10/22/world/middleeast/israel-gaza-hospital-evidence.html But that's hardly ever the case https://edition.cnn.com/2023/10/21/middleeast/cnn-investigates-forensic-analysis-gaza-hospital-blast/index.html. "In 20 years of investigating war crimes this is the first time I haven’t seen any weapon remnants. And I’ve worked three wars in Gaza." So "make of this what you will" as the saying goes.

Comment: BTW, the investigator quoted by CNN there [was](https://www.ngo-monitor.org/cnn-cites-consultant-who-teams-up-with-ngos-to-bash-israel/) previously and extensively trash talked by the pro-Israeli media, so one can hardly consider him a pro-Israeli shill.

Comment: To address the direct question posted by the OP, the only source I found that analysed the video feed from Aljazeera discredited it hitting the hospital:
https://www.nytimes.com/2023/10/24/world/middleeast/gaza-hospital-israel-hamas-video.html
'The missile seen in the video is most likely not what caused the explosion at the hospital'

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: according to independent investigations by journalists, the object shown on the Al Jazeera video feed **does NOT** seem to have caused the explosion at the hospital.

What caused the explosion at the hospital is open to debate at the moment.

**Al Jazeera Video**

An independent investigation has been carried out by the [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/10/24/world/middleeast/gaza-hospital-israel-hamas-video.html):

> The missile seen in the video is most likely not what caused the explosion at the hospital

[CNN carried out an investigation as well](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/11/02/middleeast/al-jazeera-video-gaza-hospital-blast-intl/index.html), and the conclusion was:

> CNN was able to determine that the projectile captured in the Al Jazeera broadcast was likely fired from inside Israel, not from Gaza, as was previously concluded, and unlikely to have any connection to the explosion at Al-Ahli, miles away.

The [Washington Post investigation](https://www.washingtonpost.com/investigations/2023/10/26/gaza-hospital-blast-evidence-israel-hamas/) concludes:

> Experts said that the widely circulated video probably showed an Iron Dome interceptor missile that collided with a rocket more than three miles from the hospital and most likely had nothing to do with the hospital explosion.

**What caused the explosion?**

New York Times:

> The Times’s finding does not answer what actually did cause the Al-Ahli Arab Hospital blast, or who is responsible.

CNN:

> The open-source imagery showed a huge explosion and destruction from the fire at the hospital complex, which experts said was consistent with a failed rocket crashing to the ground with unspent fuel.
>
> Weapons and explosive experts with decades of experience assessing bomb damage, who reviewed the visual evidence, told CNN they believe this to be the most likely scenario – although they caution the absence of munition remnants or shrapnel from the scene made it difficult to be sure. All agreed that the available images of evidence of the damage at the site was not consistent with an Israeli airstrike.

The Washington Post:

> None of the more than two dozen experts consulted by The Post was able to say with certainty what kind of weapon struck the hospital grounds or who fired it. But munitions experts agreed that the damage at the hospital was consistent with a rocket strike.